# Pyspark aggregation using dictionary with countDistinct functions

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, group-by

I am trying to run aggregation on a dataframe. Then I want to calculate the distinct values on every column. I generate a dictionary for aggregation with something like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct

expr = {x: "countDistinct" for x in df.columns if x is not 'id'}
df.groupBy("id").agg(expr).show()
```

I get error:

> AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'countdistinct'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;

If I use 'countDistinct' directly it works:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(countDistinct('hours'))
```

> Out[1]: DataFrame[id: int, count(hours): bigint]

This does not work:

```
df.groupBy("id").agg({'hours':'countDistinct'}).show()
```

> AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'countdistinct'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;

Any thoughts on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `countDistinct` is not a 'built-in aggregation function'.

Passing the distinct counted columns directly to `agg` would solve this:

```
cols = [countDistinct(x) for x in df.columns if x != 'id']

df.groupBy('id').agg(*cols).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more flexible if we did something like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct, sum

agg_expn = {'hours':countDistinct, 'somethingelse': sum}

temp = [agg_expn[col] for col in df.columns if agg_expn.get(col, None)]
    
df.groupby(['id']).agg(*temp)
```

This allows for different aggregate functions for different columns