# calculate the sum and countDistinct after groupby in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, aggregate-functions, distinct

I have a PySpark dataframe and would like to groupby several columns and then calculate the sum of some columns and count distinct values of another column. As `countDistinct` is not a build in aggregation function, I can't use simple expressions like the ones I tried here:

```
sum_cols = ['a', 'b']
count_cols = ['id']
exprs1 = {x: "sum" for x in sum_cols}
exprs2 = {x: "countDistinct" for x in count_cols}
exprs = {**exprs1, **exprs2}

df_aggregated = df.groupby('month','product').agg(exprs)
```

I also tried the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68293337/12934163) as `exprs2 = [countDistinct(x) for x in count_cols]` but I received an error message when I  `AssertionError: all exprs should be Column`, when I tried it only for the aggregation column.

How could I combine sum and count distinct in one aggregation? I know, that I could do it once with the `sum` columns and once with the `countDistinct` columns and than join both dataframes but there should be a solution to do that in one step...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the dict-version of [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg.html) use the version that takes a list of columns:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = ...
exprs1 = [F.sum(c) for c in sum_cols]
exprs2 = [F.countDistinct(c) for c in count_cols]

df_aggregated = df.groupby('month_product').agg(*(exprs1+exprs2))
```

If you want keep the current logic you could switch to [approx_count_distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#approx_count_distinct). Unlike `countDistinct` this function is available as SQL function.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why do you have to use `expr`, but normal aggregation should works. `countDistinct` is an aggregate function.

```py
(df
    .groupBy('month','product')
    .agg(
        F.sum('a', 'b'),
        F.countDistinct('id')
    )
).show()

# +----+-----------+-------------+
# |name|sum(field1)|count(field1)|
# +----+-----------+-------------+
# |   d|          0|            1|
# |   c|         10|            1|
# |   b|          5|            1|
# |   a|          4|            1|
# +----+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I did not mention, that I have around 20 columns starting with the same string, wich I need to sum and another x columns that I need to count (distinct values)

Comment: Same thing, you can just pass `F.sum(sum_cols)` and `F. countDistinct(count_cols)`